# How do I resolve the "undefined reference to `vtable for <<ClassName>>" error?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, constructor, vtable

I am a C++ beginner. I have a singleton 'Manager' class as shown below and I get the following error when I build the project in Eclipse:

`../src/Manager.hpp:28: undefined reference to 'vtable for Manager'`

*[The below code is the minimum (almost) to be run in your dev environment or IDEs if you want to try and reproduce the error.]*

Manager.hpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "stream_state.h"


class Manager {
    public:
       static Manager* getInstance();
       std::vector<stream_state> m_stateList;      // Why can I not remove std::?

       virtual ~Manager();      // Virtual destructor

    private:
       Manager(){};                               // ERROR points here - why so?
       Manager(Manager const&){};
       static Manager* pSingleton;
};
```

Manager.cpp

```
#include "Manager.hpp"

Manager* Manager::pSingleton = 0;

Manager* Manager::getInstance()
{
    if (pSingleton == NULL){
        pSingleton = new Manager;
    }
    return pSingleton;
}

// Other member function implementations
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Manager.hpp"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    Manager* managerObj;
    managerObj = Manager::getInstance();
    // some other code
    return 0;
}
```

stream_state.h

```
struct stream_state
{
   FILE* sp;
   bool locked;
};
```

What I have tried already (and didn't work):
1. I changed the constructor for Manager class to:
`Manager::Manager(){};`
Error:
`extra qualification 'Manager::' on member 'Manager'`

2. I removed `std::` from the line `std::vector<stream_state> m_stateList;`
`vector<stream_state> m_stateList;`
Error:
`vector does not name a type`

Can someone please explain me the `undefined reference to 'vtable for Manager'` error (and, if possible but no necessary, the `vector does not name a type error`)?

Comment: Did you implement the destructor?

Comment: You can't remove  `std::` because the standard library `vector` is defined in the `std`namespace and the compiler hasn't seen any type named "vector" in the global namespace. That might sound confusing, but your book should have a chapter or two and plenty of examples about namespaces.

Comment: Thank you both. I will read more about namespaces. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see a declaration for `~Manager()` but I don't see a definition. This needs to be in Manager.cpp.

I believe you are getting this obscure message because the `vtable` holds the addresses of all virtual functions. You only have one virtual function and you haven't defined it.

I can't reproduce the `vector` error. Once I add `~Manager::Manager() { }` to `Manager.cpp`, my version compiles fine.

Comment: You didn't add `using namespace std;` by accident?

Comment: @sfjac: Thank you so much for the very prompt and accurate reply. I added the following line of code to Manager.cpp and it all works now.
`Manager::~Manager(){};`

Comment: Done! New here. :)
Also wanted to upvote but I don't have enough reputation point. Spent over 2 hours trying to figure this out. Thanks again.

Comment: No worries. Welcome to SO!

Comment: It helped me resolve error message in reference to d'ctor, but I can't figure out how it applies to the same message except for c'tor...

Comment: It wouldn't - there are no virtual constructors in C++. The key here was that the destructor was declared virtual, which was enough to cause a vtbl to be built, IIRC, but the definition wasn't found at link time.